# Tag selection: Batch or Batch-File?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that there are both [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) and [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tags on this site, both of which primarily appear to be addressing the same thing - Windows batch files.

The description for [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) says:

> is predominantly used for Windows batch file questions. However, every
>   now and then a question related to SQL and batch

For [batch-files](/questions/tagged/batch-files) it says:

> is (hopefully) solely used for Windows batch file questions. Batch
>   files are scripts executed by the Windows

It seems to me these tags should be merged, or a synonym created.  As it is, I really can't tell *which* tag I should be using for batch file questions - or if I should use both.  Why do they remain as separate tags?  Could they be combined?

Comment: No, I disagree. While the use of `batch` in a SQL context may be rare on SO right now, it is still useful. I think it is less useful to have both `batch` and `batch-file` refer only to batch files on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I say burninate `batch` altogether. If there needs to be an SQL batch tag, then it needs its own tag. A tag should not name 2 completely separate concepts.